# Error while installing react-native-queue library

Tags: npm

I'm installing the react native queue library like so:
npm install --save react-native-queue. But I'm getting the following error:

```
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/OpenSSL.stamp
  ACTION binding_gyp_vendored_realm_target_download_realm /Users/prikshetsharma/Desktop/Humboi/node_modules/realm/vendor/realm-mac-x64
Resolved requirements: {
  SYNC_SERVER_FOLDER: 'sync',
  SYNC_ARCHIVE: 'realm-sync-node-cocoa-4.7.3.tar.gz',
  SYNC_ARCHIVE_ROOT: 'realm-sync-node-cocoa-4.7.3'
}
No lockfile found at the target, proceeding.
Download url: https://static.realm.io/downloads/sync/realm-sync-node-cocoa-4.7.3.tar.gz
Downloading realm-sync-node-cocoa-4.7.3.tar.gz [====================] (1886k)

Extracting realm-sync-node-cocoa-4.7.3.tar.gz => /Users/prikshetsharma/Desktop/Humboi/node_modules/realm/vendor/realm-mac-x64
Success
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/vendored-realm.stamp
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/realm-core.stamp
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/realm-sync.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/binding_callback_thread_observer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/collection_notifications.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/index_set.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/list.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/object.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/object_schema.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/object_store.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/placeholder.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/results.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/schema.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/shared_realm.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/thread_safe_reference.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/collection_change_builder.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/collection_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/list_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/object_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/primitive_list_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/realm_coordinator.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/results_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/transact_log_handler.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/weak_realm_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/util/uuid.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/apple/external_commit_helper.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/impl/apple/keychain_helper.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/impl/apple/network_reachability_observer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/impl/apple/system_configuration.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/util/fifo.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/server/adapter.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/server/admin_realm.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/server/global_notifier.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/impl/sync_file.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/impl/sync_metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/impl/work_queue.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/partial_sync.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/async_open_task.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/sync_config.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/sync_manager.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/sync_session.o
../src/object-store/src/sync/sync_session.cpp:567:17: warning: enumeration value
      'http_tunnel_failed' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
        switch (static_cast<ClientError>(error_code.value())) {
                ^
../src/object-store/src/sync/sync_session.cpp:567:17: note: add missing switch
      cases
        switch (static_cast<ClientError>(error_code.value())) {
                ^
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/object-store/src/object-store/src/sync/sync_user.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/object-store.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/realm/src/js_realm.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/realm/src/node/node_init.o
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:21:
In file included from ../src/node/node_string.hpp:21:
../src/node/node_types.hpp:52:42: error: no type named
      'NamedPropertyGetterCallback' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean
      'IndexPropertyGetterCallback'?
    using StringPropertyGetterCallback = v8::NamedPropertyGetterCallback;
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                         IndexPropertyGetterCallback
../src/node/node_types.hpp:50:11: note: 'IndexPropertyGetterCallback' declared
      here
    using IndexPropertyGetterCallback = Nan::IndexGetterCallback;
          ^
../src/node/node_types.hpp:53:42: error: no type named
      'NamedPropertySetterCallback' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean
      'IndexPropertySetterCallback'?
    using StringPropertySetterCallback = v8::NamedPropertySetterCallback;
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                         IndexPropertySetterCallback
../src/node/node_types.hpp:51:11: note: 'IndexPropertySetterCallback' declared
      here
    using IndexPropertySetterCallback = Nan::IndexSetterCallback;
          ^
../src/node/node_types.hpp:54:50: error: no type named
      'NamedPropertyEnumeratorCallback' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean
      'IndexedPropertyEnumeratorCallback'?
    using StringPropertyEnumeratorCallback = v8::NamedPropertyEnumeratorCallback;
                                             ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                 IndexedPropertyEnumeratorCallback
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:6317:16: note: 
      'IndexedPropertyEnumeratorCallback' declared here
typedef void (*IndexedPropertyEnumeratorCallback)(
               ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:21:
../src/node/node_string.hpp:51:32: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'isolate' was not specified
    m_str.resize(s->Utf8Length());
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2977:3: note: 
      'Utf8Length' declared here
  int Utf8Length(Isolate* isolate) const;
  ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:21:
../src/node/node_string.hpp:53:18: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type
      'v8::Isolate *' with an rvalue of type 'std::__1::basic_string<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *'
      (aka 'char *')
    s->WriteUtf8(&m_str[0], m_str.size(), 0, flags);
                 ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3037:26: note: 
      passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  int WriteUtf8(Isolate* isolate, char* buffer, int length = -1,
                         ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:24:
../src/node/node_object.hpp:33:57: error: no type named
      'ExternalOneByteStringResourceImpl' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean
      'Nan::ExternalOneByteStringResource'?
  ...new v8::ExternalOneByteStringResourceImpl(key.data(), key.size()));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         Nan::ExternalOneByteStringResource
../../nan/nan.h:193:5: note: 'Nan::ExternalOneByteStringResource' declared here
    ExternalOneByteStringResource;
    ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:24:
../src/node/node_object.hpp:33:61: error: allocating an object of abstract class
      type 'Nan::ExternalOneByteStringResource' (aka
      'v8::String::ExternalOneByteStringResource')
        node_key = v8::String::NewExternal(isolate, new v8::ExternalOneByt...
                                                            ^
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3153:25: note: 
      unimplemented pure virtual method 'data' in 'ExternalOneByteStringResource'
    virtual const char* data() const = 0;
                        ^
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3155:20: note: 
      unimplemented pure virtual method 'length' in
      'ExternalOneByteStringResource'
    virtual size_t length() const = 0;
                   ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:24:
../src/node/node_object.hpp:33:32: error: no member named 'NewExternal' in
      'v8::String'
        node_key = v8::String::NewExternal(isolate, new v8::ExternalOneByt...
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../src/node/node_object.hpp:36:77: error: no member named 'kNormalString' in
      'v8::String'
        node_key = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, key.data(), v8::String::kNorma...
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../src/node/node_object.hpp:108:32: error: no matching member function for call to
      'Get'
        names.push_back(array->Get(i)->ToString());
                        ~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3717:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:3720:43: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:25:
../src/node/node_function.hpp:41:19: error: no member named 'GetCallingContext' in
      'v8::Isolate'; did you mean 'GetCurrentContext'?
    if (!isolate->GetCallingContext().IsEmpty()) {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  GetCurrentContext
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:8825:18: note: 
      'GetCurrentContext' declared here
  Local<Context> GetCurrentContext();
                 ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:26:
../src/node/node_value.hpp:152:28: error: too few arguments to function call,
      single argument 'context' was not specified
    return value->ToString();
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:2810:3: note: 
      'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
  ^
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8config.h:431:31: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:29:
../src/node/node_class.hpp:191:23: error: no member named
      'SetNamedPropertyHandler' in 'v8::ObjectTemplate'; did you mean
      'SetIndexedPropertyHandler'?
        instance_tpl->SetNamedPropertyHandler(string_accessor.getter ? str...
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      SetIndexedPropertyHandler
/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.5/include/node/v8.h:6840:8: note: 
      'SetIndexedPropertyHandler' declared here
  void SetIndexedPropertyHandler(
       ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:29:
In file included from ../src/node/node_class.hpp:23:
../src/js_class.hpp:92:17: error: no type named 'StringPropertyGetterCallback' in
      'realm::node::Types'
    typename T::StringPropertyGetterCallback getter;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/node/node_class.hpp:368:16: note: in instantiation of template class
      'realm::js::StringPropertyType<realm::node::Types>' requested here
template<node::StringPropertyType::GetterType F>
               ^
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:29:
In file included from ../src/node/node_class.hpp:23:
../src/js_class.hpp:93:17: error: no type named 'StringPropertySetterCallback' in
      'realm::node::Types'
    typename T::StringPropertySetterCallback setter;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.cpp:19:
In file included from ../src/node/node_init.hpp:29:
../src/node/node_class.hpp:373:10: error: called object type 'int' is not a
      function or function pointer
        F(isolate, info.This(), property, return_value);
        ~^
16 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/realm/src/node/node_init.o] Error 1
```

For some reason during the installation I'm getting these 16 errors.
For some reason during the installation I'm getting these 16 errors.
For some reason during the installation I'm getting these 16 errors.
For some reason during the installation I'm getting these 16 errors.

How to fix this?